# UDP problems with virtual machine

Tags: network, virtualization, firewall

I'm using an M1 Mac and I'm trying to run a Windows .exe file called 'simhub'. It uses UDP to allow telemetry between racing games (PS5) and a Windows computer. I don't have a Windows computer, so I've tried to use UTM to create a virtual machine and run simhub.

Normally, when doing this on a Windows computer you have to modify the firewall to allow incoming UDP connections from simhub by allowing the specific IP address, however, when I try this it doesn't work. I'm unsure whether this has something to do with the firewall settings on my Mac.

Comment: It’s not your Mac’s firewall, but the port forwarding rules within UTM.  Remember, your VMs are behind a NAT network in UTM and ports need to be forwarded just like they are when sending traffic from the Internet to your Windows box/PS5